# Docker: Creating a data volume container vs simply using the -v flag with `run`?

Tags: docker, volumes

I'm reading Docker's user guide section on volumes at: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/containers/dockervolumes/

At the very first part it indicates how to create and add a volume to a container, this I will call "method 1":

> You can use the -v multiple times to mount multiple data volumes. Now, mount a single volume in your web application container.

```
$ docker run -d -P --name web -v /webapp training/webapp python app.py
```

> This will create a new volume inside a container at /webapp.

Later on it goes to talk about Data volume containers, this I will call "method 2":

> If you have some persistent data that you want to share between containers, or want to use from non-persistent containers, it’s best to create a named Data Volume Container, and then to mount the data from it.

```
$ docker create -v /dbdata --name dbstore training/postgres /bin/true
```

Here's what I don't get, what's the difference between implementing a volume through simply using the `-v` command with `docker run` (method 1) v.s. implementing a volume by using a "Data volume container" (method 2)?

It seems both ways you are just creating a volume that is persistent through the life of image's non-persistent containers, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: My understanding is that `create` creates a container but does not run it, so you get a data only container that does not consume any CPU. You can then share the volumes from this container with many other containers.

Comment: @warmoverflow Actually you can `create` a volume without putting it into a container, when i posted the question i was very confused so it's not very clear, but the difference is that in method 1 you don't put the volume inside a container, in method 2 you put it inside a container, making it a "Data Container" or something.

Comment: In method 1 the volume is inside the container, as the documentation says. And yes you can create a volume without container, but you need to use `docker volume create`, not `docker create -v`.

Comment: oh yeah sorry, that's right,  the question should be what's the difference between using `docker create -v /dbdata --name dbstore training/postgres /bin/true` vs using `docker volume create --name hello`, notice both are done with `create` but the first one gets created as a container (the documentation calls it "a data volume container"), both are meant to work as a volume that you can bind with a container when you initialize it with `run`. I might as well re-submit the question, the docker document is just kind of confusing about it.

Comment: This is just the evolution of Docker. It used to be that you need to create a container to use the data volume container pattern. I believe that `docker volume create` is a recent addition to simplify this.

Answer (score 1):

In my understanding, at least from docker 1.12 on, a volume is always the same thing: some persistant data stored somewhere on the host. But there are different ways to manage a volume:

1. Create it and mount it to a container (your method 1). With this, you can use "volumes-from" when you want to mount volumes of one container into another container
2. Create the volume using `docker volume create`, and let docker manage it. It will be saved somewhere on the host system (e.g. /var/lib/docker), but you don't really care where and how exactly.
3. Mount a host directory as a volume, in which case you know where it is mounted on your host and your are "responsible" for it.

Then, there are "tricks" (as described [here](https://madcoda.com/2016/03/docker-named-volume-explained/). For instance:

> *"if you create a named volume by running a new container from image by docker run -v my-precious-data:/data imageName, the data within the container under /data will be copied into the named volume."*

So the way you create/manage your volume might differ a bit, but it essentially always is a volume.